# How can I override two methods that call each other, while using super() to access base class methods?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, overloading, super

I have two Python3 classes:

```
class A:
    def f1(self):
        self.f2()

    def f2(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def f1(self):
        super().f1()

    def f2(self):
        pass
```

I'd like the super().f1() call to internally also call A's f2(). However, it ends up calling B's f2(). How can I change this?

Answer (score 2):

The current behaviour is the expected behaviour for the inheritance mechanism. But you can manually choose which method you call in the A class:

```
class A:
    def f1(self):
        A.f2(self)

    def f2(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is to create a "hidden" method in A (by convention, [these are prefixed with `_`](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc):

```
class A:
    def f1(self):
        self._f2()

    def f2(self):
        print("A's f2")
        self._f2()

    def _f2(self):
        print("A's _f2")


class B(A):
    def f1(self):
        super().f1()

    def f2(self):
        print("B's f2")
        pass


b = B()

b.f1()  # prints: A's _f2
```

This has the advantage that you can still override the method in B if you need to for some reason.